# Validating existence of entered e-mail

Tags: email-validation

My company has a mobile application that allows registration using your email.

A major problem we're facing is people registering with false e-mails. Is there a way to validate that the entered e-mail actually exists. We prefer not to enforce double opt-in and stick to single opt-in to provide an easier registration process.

Another problem we have is our current registered e-mails database, which is around 170 thousand e-mails. Is there a tool that can verify which of them is an actual e-mail?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The only way to verify whether an E-Mail address exists is to send an activation link to it.

Comment: Activation links are double opt-in. Isn't there any programming method to validate the email in the registration process?

Comment: nope. Sending an actual E-Mail is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Here at [Verifalia](http://verifalia.com) we provide an [email validation](http://verifalia.com) service which allows to verify email addresses using a network of worldwide validation nodes, located in multiple locations, for high quality results.

Our award-winning email validation engine emulates a mail exchanger and can be used to avoid double opt-in in several registration scenarios: it provides an HTTPS-based, RESTful [email validation API](http://verifalia.com/developers), along with free and open source SDKs, which makes integration a breeze. Furthermore, it can also be used interactively by uploading the lists of email addresses to process on our website.

Disclaimer: I am the tech lead of Verifalia.